# Start specific view of Gluon App from a notification

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I set up an alarm to show a corresponding `Notification`. The `PendingIntent` of the `Notification` is used to start the Gluon App main class. To show a `View` other than the homeView, I call `switchView(otherView)` in the `postInit` method. OtherView is shown, but without `AppBar`. While it's possible to make the `AppBar` appear, I wonder if this is the right approach.

```
@Override
public void postInit(Scene scene) {
    // additional setUp logic

    boolean showReadingView = (boolean) PlatformProvider.getPlatform().getLaunchIntentExtra("showReadingView", false);
    if (showReadingView) {
        switchView(READING_VIEW);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Platform.runLater()`? Notice that the event comes from the Android layer, in a background thread.

Comment: Yes that works. Thank you

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When triggering anything related to the JavaFX thread from another thread, we have to use `Platform.runLater()`.

Yours is a clear case of this situation: the Android thread is calling some pending intent, and as a result, the app is started again.

This should be done:

```
@Override
public void postInit(Scene scene) {
    // additional setUp logic

    boolean showReadingView = (boolean) PlatformProvider.getPlatform().getLaunchIntentExtra("showReadingView", false);
    if (showReadingView) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> switchView(READING_VIEW));
    }
}
```