# Performing an action when a push notification is clicked in Gluon based application

Tags: push-notification, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I am working in a javafx gluon mobile application. Currently I am trying to implement push notificaiton feature. I can send message to a specific device. It shows in notification tray. But when it is clicked app crashes. Below is the logcat. How do I solve this issue?

```
2020-03-27 21:44:17.373 1768-1941/? I/StatusBar: click notification, sending intent, key=0|com.pushnotes.app|123456|null|10234
2020-03-27 21:44:17.379 1552-5232/? E/ActivityManager: applyOptionsLocked: Unknown animationType=0
2020-03-27 21:44:17.381 1768-1768/? I/StatusBar: onNotificationRemoved: 0|com.pushnotes.app|123456|null|10234
2020-03-27 21:44:17.382 1768-1768/? D/StatusBar: removeNotification key=0|com.pushnotes.app|123456|null|10234 old=StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.pushnotes.app user=UserHandle{0} id=123456 tag=null key=0|com.pushnotes.app|123456|null|10234: Notification(pri=2 contentView=null vibrate=default sound=null defaults=0x2 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 category=event vis=PUBLIC))
2020-03-27 21:44:17.383 1768-1768/? D/StatusBar: update app badge num: com.pushnotes.app/,num=0,isAllowed=false,userId=0
2020-03-27 21:44:17.385 1552-5232/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:19543918
2020-03-27 21:44:17.390 1552-2742/? W/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast android.intent.action.APPLICATION_MESSAGE_UPDATE from system 1768:com.android.systemui/1000 pkg com.android.systemui. Callers=
2020-03-27 21:44:17.393 21286-21286/com.pushnotes.app I/System.out: Push notification is received : {"id":"1001", "body":"Movement Detected Message.", "title":"Movement Title."}
2020-03-27 21:44:17.413 1552-1691/? D/NotificationSQLiteLog: Pruned event entries: 80
2020-03-27 21:44:17.414 1552-5232/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.pushnotes.app/com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PushNotificationActivity
2020-03-27 21:44:17.416 1552-5232/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:19543950
2020-03-27 21:44:17.416 2431-2465/? I/octvm_klo: klo lock
2020-03-27 21:44:17.417 1552-5232/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
2020-03-27 21:44:17.418 1552-5232/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.pushnotes.app/javafxports.android.FXActivity
2020-03-27 21:44:17.419 4169-4445/? D/PowerKeeper.Event: notifyAMCrash packageName: 0, pid:21286
2020-03-27 21:44:17.424 21286-21286/com.pushnotes.app I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21286 SIG: 9
2020-03-27 21:44:17.431 531-531/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/21286/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/ActivityManager: Failed setting process group of 21286 to 9
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given thread 21308 does not exist
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Native Method)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.applyOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:21384)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:21901)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processCurBroadcastLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:291)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:1307)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:805)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue$BroadcastHandler.handleMessage(BroadcastQueue.java:176)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.432 1552-1568/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.448 2431-2465/? I/octvm_klo: get wanted event[mask:128, name:data_app_crash@1585325657422.txt] from the watchset
2020-03-27 21:44:17.448 2431-2465/? I/octvm_klo: start gathering logcat log...
2020-03-27 21:44:17.450 4792-4792/? D/TouchAssistant: getPackageNameFromPid packageName:com.microsoft.launcher
2020-03-27 21:44:17.450 4792-4792/? D/TouchAssistant: onTopAppChanged packageName:com.microsoft.launcher
2020-03-27 21:44:17.450 4792-4792/? D/TouchAssistant: onTopAppChanged show
2020-03-27 21:44:17.451 4792-4792/? D/TouchAssistant: AssistantWindowHelper isWeltHidden
2020-03-27 21:44:17.451 4792-4792/? D/TouchAssistant: AssistantWindowHelper forceSlideAway()
2020-03-27 21:44:17.453 4792-4792/? D/TouchAssistant: updateAll and mViewAdded = true
2020-03-27 21:44:17.454 1768-1768/? E/BoostFramework: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
2020-03-27 21:44:17.505 2431-2465/? I/octvm_klo: gathering logcat log done
2020-03-27 21:44:17.505 2431-2465/? I/octvm_klo: klo unlock
2020-03-27 21:44:17.518 712-1545/? D/DnsProxyBlocker: remove uid(10173) for Firewall
2020-03-27 21:44:17.534 1552-1563/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 6
2020-03-27 21:44:17.534 1552-2604/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{fd2848c u0 com.pushnotes.app/javafxports.android.FXActivity}
2020-03-27 21:44:17.534 1552-2604/? W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{851b1ac u0 SurfaceView - com.pushnotes.app/javafxports.android.FXActivity} from container Window{fd2848c u0 com.pushnotes.app/javafxports.android.FXActivity}
2020-03-27 21:44:17.537 1552-2761/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.pushnotes.app (pid 21286) has died: vis  +99T 
2020-03-27 21:44:17.540 4169-4445/? D/PowerKeeper.Event: notifyAMProcDied pacakageName: com.pushnotes.app, pid:21286
2020-03-27 21:44:17.542 1552-1563/? W/WindowManager: Failed looking up window
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@14d47d5 does not exist
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9701)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9692)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1836)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:701)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.542 1552-1563/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: null
2020-03-27 21:44:17.554 1552-2761/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:19544088
2020-03-27 21:44:17.560 1552-1575/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:19544094
2020-03-27 21:44:17.561 1768-1768/? D/EventBus: [1768, u0] send(TaskSnapshotChangedEvent)
2020-03-27 21:44:17.562 1552-2038/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:19544096
2020-03-27 21:44:17.570 687-753/? D/ThermalEngine: sensor_wait: case_therm Wait done.
```

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong based on that stacktrace. Edit your question and post your build.gradle and AndroidManifest?

Comment: Actually while receiving push notification I updated my UI(setting text of a label) directly inside RuntimeArgsService's if present method. I then moved that code into Platform.runLater(). Then it works fine. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912175/start-specific-view-of-gluon-app-from-a-notification?rq=1) thread helped me to solve my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Jose Pereda. I've got another question too. Is it possible to open a specific view when the app is either closed or runs in background? If it is possible would you give small explanation on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can perform any action you want when the user taps the notification, via [runnable](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/Notification.html). Note that you have to recreate the notification upon app startup. One example can be found in the [Devoxx app](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/master/DevoxxClientMobile/src/main/java/com/devoxx/util/DevoxxNotifications.java#L444).